# Reading .CSV for storing Fortran array

Tags: arrays, matlab, csv, fortran

My problem is that I have an array `a(2,3,4)` and I transfer this array to Fortran as a CSV file.

Then, in Fortran, I created the array and try to read it.

But when I check the value of the same element (for example `a(2,1,1)`) the value that Fortran shows me is not the same value at the same element in Matlab.

I copy the code that I have developed

```
program test_dot_prod          

    real, dimension(:, :, :), allocatable :: a 

    open (unit=102, file='a.csv',  status='old', action='read')          

    allocate(a(2, 3, 4))

    read(102, *), a    

    write(*,*) a(2, 1, 1)

    write(*,*) a(1, 2, 1) 

    write(*,*) a(1, 1, 2)     

end
```

For example, the value that I have in Matlab is `a(2,1,1) = 0.3012`

And in Fortran, the same point `a(2,1,1) = 0.4709`

The .CSV that I transfer to fortran has the following structure.

```
0.20774,0.47092,0.84431,0.22592,0.22766,0.3111,0.43021,0.90488,0.43887,0.25806,0.5949,0.60284

0.30125,0.23049,0.19476,0.17071,0.4357,0.92338,0.18482,0.97975,0.11112,0.40872,0.26221,0.71122
```

Comment: I think you have stored your array as row-major ( a(1,1,1) a(1,1,2) a(1,1,3) ...) . but Fortran reads arrays as Coulomn-major ( a(1,1,1) a(2,1,1) a(1,2,1) ...)

Comment: matlab is also column major, but it gets transposed for the csv. It is also reduced to 2d. (because csv doesnt support higher dimension) Your best bet is to not use csv, but get matlab to write the data in its native ordering.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the welcome [tour] and read [ask]. Please do not link to files at some file sharing service. We need the question to make sense in the future. Please copy some relevant part of the CSV file and [edit] it here into the question as text. I think that two or three lines will be enough.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir F, I have edited my post, following your instructions. Thank you forr all the people , who has try to help me in special to agentp, that give me the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following my comment, it turns out to be not so simple to coax matlab to write a multidimensional array in its native storage order.  You need to make a flattened copy,

```
tmp=reshape(a,numel(a),1);
save(filename,'tmp','-ASCII')
```

you can also use `dlmwrite`

fortran will read this file using a single `read(unit,*)a` and give you the correct ordering.

EDIT..this avoids making a copy, but you need to supply an appropriate format specifier:

```
fileID = fopen(filename,'w');
fprintf(fileID,'%12.8f',a);
fclose(fileID);
```